# ASP.Net Mvc Ajax Request in Progress

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am currently using  @Ajax.ActionLink to call some controller action in ajax fashion .Is there any way to detect if there is already a ajax request running/pending  on page?The functionality i want is pretty basic i.e. once user clicks the link he should wait for either request to succeed or fail.He should be allowed to click it again( generate a new request to server).

I could have disabled the link but would not like to do that(i guess a href cant be disabled)

Comment: Add the full `@Ajax.ActionLink()` code

Comment: `code` @Ajax.ActionLink("Click Me", "ajaxactions",  new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "content", HttpMethod = "Post", Confirm = "Are you Sure ?", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter, LoadingElementId = "im", OnComplete = "end()", OnBegin = "start()" }, new { @id = "btn", @class = "btn btn-default" })
`code`

Comment: You have both `OnBegin` and `OnComplete` functions, so you could add a javascrip variable (say) `var IsExecuting = false;`, then in `OnBegin` if its `true`, cancel the ajax call, otherwise set it to `true`. Then in `OnComplete`, set it to false. The user will still be able to click it but it wont do anything. The other option would be jquery (which is better anyway)

Comment: @StephenMuecke So would OnBegin would be invoked first and then the Controller code fired or vice versa ?

Comment: `OnBegin` is called before the ajax call to the server, and it can return `false` to cancel the ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

This Code will check for any executing ajax request before making a new ajax request. You can subscribe  OnSuccess, OnFailure callbacks also :

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home", new AjaxOptions { 
    OnBegin = "return onBegin();",
    OnComplete = "onComplete",
    UpdateTargetId = "article_site"
})
```

and then:

```
var request_executing = false;
function onBegin() {
    if (request_executing == true) {return false ;}
    request_executing = true;
    return true;
}

function onComplete() {
    request_executing = false;
}
```

Or a jquery alternative (so you don't need that bloated `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` file)

```
@Html.ActionLink("Click Me", "ajaxactions", null, new { id = "btn", @class = "btn btn-default" })

var isExecuting = false;
$('#btn').click(function(e) {
  if(isExecuting) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
  }
  isExecuting = true;
  $(this).addClass('someClass'); // optional - to give some visual effect to the link while loading
  $.get('@Url.Action("ajaxactions")', function(data) {
    $('#content').append(data);
    $(this).removeClass('someClass');
    isExecuting = false;
  });
});
```

Comment: So would OnBegin would be invoked first and then the Controller code fired or vice versa ?

Comment: yes onBegin function will check if it can make request, if onBegin function returns false then your action will be cancelled otherwise it will call action. i have update the above function little bit.

Comment: @VaibhavJain, You need to change `OnBegin = "onBegin",` to `OnBegin = "return onBegin()",` otherwise the ajax call will not be cancelled.

Comment: That why you got the upvote :). And if you don't mind will edit it to include a jquery alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Try jQuery ajax. It can do async and sync requests to server. It's quite simple to use. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ async=true by default.

Comment: in that case i would miss the simplicity @Ajax.Actionlink offers.I would then need to bind a function with on click and move towards a more jquery sort of code.right ?

Comment: sure, but try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.oncomplete(v=vs.118).aspx